# Google maps API JAVASCRIPT - Add more rectangles (dynamic)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a little problem with my "app" using google maps. I just want to dynamic add a rectangle into my map and each rectangle add a little event...

My code:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(this.canvas, "click", function(event)
    {
        var left   = event.latLng.lng() - 0.1;
        var right  = event.latLng.lng() + 0.1;
        var top    = event.latLng.lat() - 0.1;
        var bottom = event.latLng.lat() + 0.1;

        var rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
            bounds: {north: top, south: bottom, east: right, west: left},
            editable: true,
            draggable: true,
            fillColor: 'blue',
            strokeColor: 'blue'
        });

        rectangle.setMap(map.canvas);

        rectangle.addListener("rightclick", function ()
            {
                if(rectangle.editable)
                {
                    rectangle.setOptions({
                        editable: false,
                        draggable: false,
                        fillColor: "black",
                        strokeColor: "black"
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    rectangle.setOptions({
                        editable: true,
                        draggable: true,
                        fillColor: "blue",
                        strokeColor: "blue"
                    });
                }
            });
    });
```

All what I want is just add new rectangle after click, and when I use right click -> enable / disable rectangle...

This code works fine, but when I lock one or more rectangles, all rectangles does not move and they are !draggable.

Can you help me with this? Thanks!

live demo : https://jsfiddle.net/3fuf5bqo/ just 2x click on the map (create 2 rectangles) and after this just click (right click) on one of them - both of them does not move

Comment: I don't see the problem you are describing.  Unless you are expecting all rectangles to become editable and draggable when you rightclick on one of them.  The rectangles are editable and draggable when blue and not editable or draggable when black.

Comment: There seems to be an issue of right-click with rectangles. When I tried similar code with markers only the ones with draggable false were not draggable.

Answer (score 0):

HMMMM, the problem was in "rightclick" event, when I use just "click" or "dbclick" the problem was solved... I do not get it... :-D but it works